# React Checkbox from Postgres Database

Tags: reactjs, database, postgresql, checkbox, knex.js

I'm getting an array of users from a database table called users. One of the fields is a checkbox with a default of false.  I'm not able to change the checkbox.  When I got the array from a static page it worked fine, but not working after fetching from database.  The handleChange function is what I'm using to change checkboxes.  The array that comes back from componentDidMount is like this:

```
{
 "id": 455,
    "firstname": "Sally",
    "lastname": "Sue",
    "company": "Baltic Explorations",
    "city": "houston",
    "phone": "2058231111",
    "email": "sally@gmail.com",
    "ischecked": false
},
```

App.js

```
class App extends Component  {

    constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
    network: [],
    networkfilter:[],
    suggest:suggest,
    searchfield:'',
    searchsuggest:'',
    route:'signin',
    routed:false,
    isSignedIn:false,
    user: {
      id:'',
      firstname: '',
      lastname: '',
      phone:'',
      city:'',
      email:'',
      company:'',
      ischecked:false

    }

}
this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);
this.handleClick=this.handleClick.bind(this);

}

componentDidMount() {
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/data')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {

    this.setState({network:data})})


}

loadUser = (data) => {
  this.setState({user: {
      id:data.id,
      firstname: data.firstname,
      lastname: data.lastname,
      phone: data.phone,
      city:data.city,
      email:data.email,
      company:data.company,
      ischecked:data.ischecked


  }})
}

onSearchChange=(event)=> {
  this.setState({searchfield:event.target.value})

}

onSuggestChange=(event)=> {
  this.setState({searchsuggest:event.target.value})

}

handleChange(id,route) {

    const updatedNetwork = network.map(netw => {
      if (netw.id===id) {
        netw.ischecked = !netw.ischecked       
      }
      return netw
    })
    return {
      network:updatedNetwork

    } 
}

render() {
  const filteredNetwork = this.state.network.filter(netw => {
    return netw.lastname.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchfield.toLowerCase())
  })

  const filteredSuggestions = this.state.suggest.filter(sugg => {
    return sugg.location.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchsuggest.toLowerCase())

  })

  return (
    <div className = "tc">
    <Navigation 
      isSignedIn ={this.state.isSignedIn}
      onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange}
      routed={this.state.routed}
     /> 

    {
    this.state.route==='home' ?
      <div> 
      <h2 className = "ml6">All Network</h2> 
         <Searchbox 
          searchChange = {this.onSearchChange}
          onRouteChange = {this.onRouteChange}
          routed={this.state.routed}

          /> 
         <NetworkArray 
             network={filteredNetwork}
             handleChange = {this.handleChange} 
             handleClick ={this.handleClick} 
             selectedCard={this.state.suggest}
             onRouteChange = {this.onRouteChange} 


             />
      </div> 
     : (
      this.state.route==='mynetwork' ? (
        <div>
         <h2 className = "ml6">My Network</h2>
         <Searchbox searchChange = {this.onSearchChange}

           />
          }
          <MyNetworkArray
            handleChange = {this.handleChange}
            network = {filteredNetwork}

           />
          ... moreComponents loaded here removed for brevity
export default App;
```

Card Component

```
import React from 'react';

const Card = (props) => {

    return(
        <div className = 'pointer bg-light-green dib br3 pa3 ma2 grow  shadow-5'
        onClick = {() => props.handleClick(props.id)}>

        <div>
            <h3>{props.name}</h3>
            <p>{props.company}</p> 
            <p>{props.phone}</p>
            <p>{props.email}</p>
            <p>{props.city}</p> 

         </div>
         <div> 
            My Network
            <input className ="largeCheckbox"
                type = "checkbox"
                checked={props.ischecked}
                onChange={()=> props.handleChange(props.id)}
                    /> 
            </div> 
         </div> 

        )
}

export default Card;
```

How can I go about updating the checkboxes, and that when user logs in, it keeps track of the checkboxes that particular user has checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  handleChange(id, route) {
    const updatedNetwork = network.map(netw => {
      if (netw.id === id) {
        netw.ischecked = !netw.ischecked;
      }
      return netw;
    });
    return {
      network: updatedNetwork
    };
  }
```

This should be giving you all kinds of errors, as `network` is undefined. Is it possible you were using a global or imported value to provide a dummy server response, then forgot to change it to component state? I'd expect to see a reference to `this.state.network`.

Comment: You're right.  This was coming from a static page, and i have this at the top:
import {network} from './NetworkData';   When i remove it, i get network undefined.  I'm trying to change everything to update the database.

Comment: OK Awesome, i'm able to change the checkboxes now using this.state.  But i guess the BIG question is how would i update a database to show the checkboxes that were checked when the user logs in?  Would i need another table etc.?

Comment: It's a little hard to tell without knowing how you're storing the data currently. However, I assume you have some sort of `users_networks` join table, in addition to `users` and `networks`? If that's the case your query will just add another row to said table each time the user checks a box. If not, maybe that's your next move.